# copy text from url with a batch file

Tags: batch-file

I was wondering if there's anyway to copy the content of a raw pastebin page to batch :

```
example :
https://pastebin.com/raw/J5xb0eUX
```

then use the echo command to display it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should download the raw code in the temporary folder and edit it with the command Type, like this code :

```bat
@echo off
Title Download code from pastebin and display it with batch
Set "url=https://pastebin.com/raw/J5xb0eUX"
for %%# in (%url%) do ( set "File=%tmp%\%%~n#.txt" )
Call :Download "%url%" "%File%"
If exist "%File%" Type "%File%"
Pause>nul & Exit
::*********************************************************************************
:Download <url> <File>
Powershell.exe -command "(New-Object System.Net.WebClient).DownloadFile('%1','%2')"
exit /b
::*********************************************************************************
```

***EDIT :***

Here is another example to show code and save it in a new text file :

```bat
@echo off
Title Download code from pastebin and display it with batch
Set "url=https://pastebin.com/raw/vzx1dEdW"
for %%# in (%url%) do ( set "File=%tmp%\%%~n#.txt" )
Call :Download "%url%" "%File%"
If exist "%File%" ( 
    ( Type "%File%")>con
Rem to save the contents in new text file
( Type "%File%" > Multi_Downloading_Files.txt)
)
Start "" Multi_Downloading_Files.txt
Pause>nul & Exit
::*********************************************************************************
:Download <url> <File>
Powershell.exe -command "(New-Object System.Net.WebClient).DownloadFile('%1','%2')"
exit /b
::*********************************************************************************
```